# Import Adobe Premiere Proxy files encoded separately with FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, premiere, intermediate

I'm trying to work with a bunch (hundreds) of 4k HEVC video clips, and so far it seems like my laptop is a bit too slow to edit them effectively. I have read [guides](https://blog.frame.io/2017/03/20/premiere-pro-proxies/) that talk about ingesting proxy files, which is great but involves running Adobe Media encoder on my macbook.

Ideally I don't want to do any proxy file encoding on my macbook since it slows down my laptop too much. I want to create the proxy files on a separate unix server using ffmpeg, then copy them onto my laptop when they're done. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that you can attach proxies later in Premiere by right clicking on your source files and going to the Proxy > Attach Proxies menu. In there, clicking attach brings up a file dialog to get the proxy files.[image]

Comment: You can mark your own answer as the accepted answer if this solves your problem.